Put CSV file column saved as json object to HTTP request - Jmeter
I have CSV file with different columns, one column having json object value and all other columns having string value, how can I read column which is having json object from csv file for my Jmeter setup?
Please suggest?
Expected request :
{
"Id":"1",
"Type" : "Any",
"User":"Test1",
"Description" : "This is test",
"DetailAtrr" : {"Subject":"1907","Percentage":"56","Grade":"A+"}
}



@Dmitri T Can you help sir

If you using CSV (comma-separated-values file) normally you cannot have JSON there because JSON contains commas in the majority of cases.
If you want to use commas and quotation marks in your test data the "cell" containing these characters should be enclosed in quotation marks, and any quotation marks inside the "cell" value should be doubled to escape them.
See RFC-4180 for more details
So if you amend your CSV file to look like this:
Id,Type,User,Description,Details
1,Any,Test1,This is a test,"""{""Subject"":""1907"",""Percentage"":""56"",""Grade"":""A+""}"""

and set up your CSV Data Set Config to look like this:

you should be able to refer the variables values like ${Id}, ${Type}, etc. where required.

Thanks for reply @Ivan G, I have mapped variables for other columns like you mentioned, but for Details column i am using JSR223 preprocessor, do you have any idea how to read this json object?
